# Как устранить ошибку при подключении JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой в `Node.js`:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Она возникает, когда я пытаюсь подключить в скрипт JSON-файл.

Comment: вы там пишите что ли `<script src="...json">` что ли? или как подключаете?

Comment: нет. я подключаю его в скрипт посредством import dictionary from '../json/dictionary.json';

Comment: это реальный файл, или он генерируется по запросу?

Comment: это реальный файл.

Comment: @ОлегИщук, это в Node.js? Чтобы мне ответить пишите @ перед моим именем.

Comment: @Bharata, да. Это, вроде бы, означает, что у chrome не все гладко с es6 модулями.

Comment: @ОлегИщук Нет, это означает что вы неверно билдите проект. Если вообще билдите. `json` файл не может быть `es6` модулем, так как это не `javascript` чтобы сделать его таковым - создайте файл `../json/dictionary.js`, где будет `export default { .... }`